# Error in my HTML codes when trying to place in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

This is my HTML code for an image where I can hover over and view another picture

```
<a href="ProductDetail.php?cat_id=1"><img class = "images" src = "images/menTop pic1.jpg" onmouseover = "src = 'images/menTop pic1 hover.jpg'" onmouseout = "src = 'images/menTop pic1.jpg'"></a>
```

I tried to put it in my PHP and replace the IDs and picture with variables but I cannot seem to get it working due to the insane amount of " and '.

```
echo "<a href='ProductDetail.php?cat_id=".$itemid."'><img class = 'images' src = '".$imagefile."' onmouseover = 'src = '".$imagefile2."'' onmouseout = 'src = '".$imagefile."''></a>";
```

As of now it shows the first image but does not show the second image when I hover over the picture. Can anyone help me solve this problem? Appreciate the help, thanks!

EDIT: 
        $mysql = new mysqli("localhost", "root", null, "webdb");

```
    $stmt = $mysql ->prepare("select itemid, itemname, imagefile, imagefile2, itemprice, itemcolor from webdb.item ORDER by itemid ASC");
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($itemid, $itemname, $imagefile, $imagefile2, $itemprice, $itemcolor);

    $column = 1;

    echo "<div class = content>";
        echo "<table align = 'center' style = 'width:80%'>";
            while($stmt->fetch()) {
                  if ($column == 1) { 
                    echo "<tr>"; 
                  } 
                        echo "<th>";
                            echo "<a href='ProductDetail.php?cat_id=".$itemid."'><img class = 'images' src = '".$imagefile."' onmouseover = 'src = '".$imagefile2."'' onmouseout = 'src = '".$imagefile."''></a>";
                            echo "<a href='ProductDetail.php?cat_id=".$itemid."'><h4>".$itemname."</h4></a>";
                            echo "<p>".$itemcolor."</p>";
                            echo "<p>".$itemprice."</p>";
                        echo "</th>";

                  if ($column == 3) { 
                     $column = 1; 
                     echo "</tr>"; 
                  } 
                  else { 
                     $column++; 
                  }     
            }

        echo "</table>";
    echo "</div>";
    $stmt->close();
    $mysql->close();
```

Currently, this is my block of codes where I am trying to extract every row of data from my item database and to place it nicely in columns of 3 in a webpage. Therefore, if there is a way of placing it in HTML instead of PHP, I'd love if you guys can teach me how to.

Comment: You need to escape the single quotes on the JS attribute. You get a PHP error as well?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<?php echo'<a href ="ProductDetail.php?cat_id='.$itemid.'"><img class="images" src="'.$imagefile.'"
  onmouseover="src=\''.$imagefile2.'\';"
  onmouseout="src=\''.$imagefile.'\';"/></a>'; ?>
```

This should solve your problem

Comment: Whats up with the downvoting? the answer was marked as the correct answer

Answer (score 2):

Instead of echoing html with PHP like that, it will be much more readable if you write the HTML outside of the PHP-block:

```
while($stmt->fetch()) {
    if ($column == 1) { 
        echo "<tr>"; 
    }
    // Close the PHP block
    ?>

    <th>
        <a href="ProductDetail.php?cat_id=<?= $itemid ?>"><img class="images" src="<?= $imagefile ?>" onmouseover="src='<?= $imagefile2 ?>'" onmouseout="src='<?= $imagefile ?>'"></a>
        <a href="ProductDetail.php?cat_id=<?= $itemid ?>"><h4><?= $itemname ?></h4></a>
        <p><?= $itemcolor ?></p>
        <p><?= $itemprice ?></p>
    </th>

    <?php
    // Start the PHP block again
    if ($column == 3) { 
        $column = 1; 
        echo "</tr>"; 
    } 
    else { 
        $column++; 
    }     
}
```

This way, not only will it be more readable, but you won't you need to escape the quotes + any decent IDE will be able to syntax highlight the HTML as well, making it much easier to spot mistakes.

Comment: yeah i agree but that statement has to be in the while($stmt->fetch()) to receive all the data I am fetching from the database which is why I am placing it in PHP

Comment: @SebastianOng That doesn't matter. You can simply replace your echo with this and it will work exactly the same.

Comment: I've edited my post, I don't know what you meant by replacing echo and how so is it possible if you show me how?

Comment: @SebastianOng I've updated the answer to show you how you can use it in your loop.

Answer (score 0):

This part is the problem:

```
[...] onmouseover = 'src = '".$imagefile2."'' onmouseout = 'src = '".$imagefile."''></a>";
```

some single quotes that should be replaced by escaped double quotes:

```
[...] onmouseover = 'src = \"".$imagefile2."\"' onmouseout = 'src = \"".$imagefile."\"'></a>";
```

Answer (score -1):

You should remove one ' at

```
onmouseover = 'src = '".$imagefile2."''.
```

It should be

```
onmouseover = 'src = '".$imagefile2."'.
```

Comment: This won't work. You have un-escaped single quotes inside single quotes.